# Backend of next.js is Internal Server Error when I hosting to firebase with firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, next.js, postman, hosting, firebase-admin

I use a javascript file to export databast like that

```
let admin = require("firebase-admin");

let serviceAccount = require("./my-firebase-adminsdk.json");

if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL:
      "https://my-databaseURL.firebasedatabase.app",
  });
}

let db = admin.database();
module.exports = db;
```

and I import db like that

```
let db = require("../../firebase/firebase-admin");

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "backend of next.js is running" });
  }
}
```

It works well in http://localhost:3000

But when i do `firebase deploy`,It show that `Internal Server Error` in postman

And I delete `let db = require("../../firebase/firebase-admin");` like that

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "backend of next.js is running" });
  }
}
```

It works well,can anyone tell me why

I use it half year ago and It works well in firebase hosting.I do not know what happen